# AngularJS Routing & jQuery Conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, url-routing

everyone. Has anyone else encountered `jQuery` console errors when routing to new views with `AngularJS`?

An example of the error is

`Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #/projects/project-id`

Everything still works, but that error gets thrown whenever a link is clicked that is related to my Angular routing. The error shows up attributed to `jQuery`, so I assume it's an issue with it not liking links starting with "`#/`"

HTML

```
<div class="project" ng-repeat="project in projects">
    <a href="#/projects/{{project.id}}">
        <h4>{{ project.name }}</h4>
        <p>{{ project.subtitle }}</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

JS

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
     $routeProvider
     .when('/', {
         controller: "HomeController",
         templateUrl: "js/angular/views/home-view.html"
     })
     .when('/projects/:projectId', {
         controller: 'ProjectController',
         templateUrl: 'js/angular/views/project-view.html',
     })
     .otherwise({
         redirectTo: '/'
     });
});
```

The console error isn't a showstoppper, because like I said, everything still works. But if anyone has encountered this before and has a fix, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: jQuery and angular sometimes don't play well together. Whats your jQuery look like?

Answer (score 1):

Set the $locationProvider to work in HTML5 mode. See here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider

An example of how to use it would be the following:

```
app.config(function ($locationProvider) {
  // use the HTML5 History API
  $locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
  });
});
```